# Custom Hook: Not all constituents of type 'xxx' are callable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I understand this ts error (`TS2349`) appears because of not consistent type in the return tuple. But is it the right way to manage this error by adding 'as const' on custom hook's return value?

```
// useCustomHook.tsx

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default (key: string, initValue: string = '') => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => localStorage.getItem(key) || initValue)

  useEffect(() => { localStorage.setItem(key, value) }, [key, value]);

  return [value, setValue] as const; // without 'as const' =>
                                     // TypeScript error TS2349 on hook calls
                                     
}
```

```
// Component.tsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import useCustomHook from 'components/hooks/useCustomHook';

const Component = () => {

  const [someKey, setSomeKey] = useCustomHook('some_key');

  useEffect(() => {

    setSomeKey('value'); // without 'as const' in custom hook it fails to compile:
                         // This expression is not callable.
                         // Not all constituents of type
                         // 'string | Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>'
                         // are callable. Type 'string' has no call signatures.

  }, [setSomeKey]);

  return (
    <>{someKey}</>
  )
}
```

n.b. "react" : "^16.13.1" "typescript": "~3.7.2"